# Transferring an iTunes library between Apple IDs, users AND computers?

Tags: itunes, mac, macbook-pro, apple-id, file-transfer

Okay.
So I finally got my own MacBook Pro after a few years of sharing my mother's Mac. I have my own Apple ID and everything. The thing is... I spent hours, if not Days uploading music onto her computer from legitimate sources and hard-copy CDs. I named, cataloged, sorted and optimised my playlists and I do not wish to do such a thing again, especially considering this MacBook Pro has no built in disk reader.

I understand that I can 'share' libraries with my mother's computer, but that only seems like a short term solution as I only have access to said library when I'm in close proximity to her Mac, and I see no way of simply transferring the data.

**Is there a way that I can transfer an iTunes Library from one Apple ID to another over separate computers?**

Answer (score 2):

If it's music you ripped yourself, or is otherwise DRM-free, you can just copy the iTunes library and files over to the new computer via networked file sharing, or a USB hard drive or similar. When you open iTunes it should read the library files and load everything automatically.

Apple's [support article on moving your music to a new computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your iTunes library is anything like mine and is somewhere above 200GB, I recommend doing a [firewire transfer](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6815) from one computer to the other. If your computers have different firewire plug shapes, the adaptors are relatively easy to find in big box electronic stores. I found mine at Best Buy.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a very detailed article on this:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204318

It includes the authorization, purchase / download aspects in addition to how to step by step move the files and library itself.